Index Function - Use One Formula to Generate the Result List with Two Variables
I will use index to locate specific value in the range.
The Range



Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4




Tom
Apple
Orange
Banana


John
Earl
Camomile
Sri Lanka


Peter
Van
Bus
Tram


Patrick
A4
A3
A5



The row number and column number is kept in this table.  These numbers are subject to changes.
Index Function Parameter



Row
Column




2
3


3
2


4
4


2
2


4
3


3
1



Anticipated Result



Anticipated Result




Orange


Earl


Tram


Apple


Bus


John



Please see my shared spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12JDr0J3Sbu-ZUpWveMswnPXOtP4EcA-eZzxFsV2ALlE/edit?usp=sharing
It is straightforward to use formula by inputting formulas alongside each pair of parameter.  However, I want to make it simple.  Can I input one formula in cell D11 to achieve the same result?

Using BYROW:
You can also use BYROW as an alternative solution.
=BYROW(A11:B16,LAMBDA(x,INDEX(A2:D5, INDEX(x,,1),INDEX(x,,2))))

Sample Output:

Reference/s:
BYROW function
INDEX

Use MAP:
=MAP(A11:A16,B11:B16,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(A2:D6,r,c)))


Thanks @z.. , would you please also advise, in my example above, there are 2 variables, how about if there are 3 variables?  How the lambda function would be?

you need to provide 3 arrays and 3 placeholder variables rather than 2. See MAP function
